# Place command resulted by a git alias to bash history

Tags: bash, git

The following git alias give a menu to select the remote and branch name for fetch command.

```
git config --global alias.fh '!git fetch $(git remote | rofi -dmenu) $(git branch | sd "^[\*]*[ ]*" ""| rofi -dmenu)'
```

The end result of this alias (shown by `echo git fetch $(git remote | rofi -dmenu) $(git branch | sd "^[\*]*[ ]*" ""| rofi -dmenu)`) is something like:

```
git fetch origin1 branch2
git fetch origin2 branch3
git fetch origin3 branch1
```

My issue is, in bash history I only get `git fh` when the alias is run. However, In history, I would like to have whatever was the end result of the last invocation of `git fh` (something like `git fetch origin2 branch3`).

How can I do that?

Comment: It is better to save the result in a file then. Bash history only returns the commands executed.

Comment: bash shell output history file location https://askubuntu.com/questions/758991/bash-shell-output-history-file-location

Comment: You can append an arbitrary line to history with `history -s ARG ...`. This creates a single new entry containing all arguments given.

Comment: fwiw : a more script friendly command to list branches is : `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads`  (but not much shorter than `git branch | sd ...` I'm afraid)